# Pixel RNN Pytorch Implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, lstm, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement Pixel RNN in pytorch, but I cannot seem to find any documentation on this. The main parts of Pixel RNN are Row LSTM and BiDiagonal LSTM, so I am looking for some code of these algorithms to better understand what they are doing. Specifically, I am confused as to these algorithms calculate one row and diagonal at once, respectively. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you succeed in creating a Pixel RNN in Pytorch? If so, will you consider making it public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary**

Here is an in progress partial implementation:

https://github.com/carpedm20/pixel-rnn-tensorflow

Here is a description of Row LSTM and BiDiagonal LSTM at google deepmind:

https://towardsdatascience.com/summary-of-pixelrnn-by-google-deepmind-7-min-read-938d9871d6d9

---

**Row LSTM**

From the linked deepmind blog:

The hidden state of a pixel, red in the image below, is based on the "memory" of the triangular three pixels before it. Because they are in a "row", we can compute in parallel, speeding up computation. We sacrifice some context information (using more history or memory) for the ability to do this parallel computation and speed up training.

[image]

The actual implementation relies on several other optimizations and is quite involved. From the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.06759.pdf):

> The computation proceeds as follows. An LSTM layer has an
>   input-to-state component and a recurrent state-to-state component that
>   together determine the four gates inside the LSTM core. To enhance
>   parallelization in the Row LSTM the input-to-state component is first
>   computed for the entire two-dimensional input map; for this a k × 1
>   convolution is used to follow the row-wise orientation of the LSTM
>   itself. The convolution is masked to include only the valid context
>   (see Section 3.4) and produces a tensor of size 4h × n × n,
>   representing the four gate vectors for each position in the input map,
>   where h is the number of output feature maps. To compute one step of
>   the state-to-state component of the LSTM layer, one is given the
>   previous hidden and cell states hi−1 and ci−1, each of size h × n × 1.
>   The new hidden and cell states hi , ci are obtained as follows:

[image]

> where xi of size h × n × 1 is row i of the input map, and ~ represents the convolution operation and  the elementwise
>   multiplication. The weights Kss and Kis are the kernel weights for the
>   state-to-state and the input-to-state components, where the latter is
>   precomputed as described above. In the case of the output, forget and
>   input gates oi , fi and ii , the activation σ is the logistic sigmoid
>   function, whereas for the content gate gi , σ is the tanh function.
>   Each step computes at once the new state for an entire row of the
>   input map

**Diagonal BLSTM**

Diagonal BLSTM's were developed to leverage the speedup of parallelization without sacrificing as much context information. A node in a DBLSTM looks to its left and above it; since those nodes have also looked to the left and above, the conditional probability of a given node depends in some sense on all of its ancestors. Otherwise, the architectures are very similar. From the deepmind blog:

[image]

Comment: So if I understand, we are still computing the image pixel by pixel, it's just that we are using an entire row at once to compute a pixel?

Comment: Still updating the answer with details :) But yes in theory, they key insight is that the memory steps can be sped up. (And you don't have to use the entire row, it's just that you can use nothing outside the row so that you can paralellilize) In practice there are several important optimizations, which I'll try to summarize

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have one last question: Where does the memory of the previous 3 pixels come from? Does each pixel have an lstm cell, or is one row-lstm contained in a single lstm cell? Also, do we do row-lstm for each pixel in the image?

Comment: No problem; if you find it helpful, you're allowed to upvote and accept (although you don't have to do either). There are a few ways to implement LSTM's, but in this case a single LSTM layer contains per pixel data. Traditionally, to figure out the output of an lstm layer at (i,j), you need the value at (i-1,j) & (i,j-1), so you need to compute each node iteratively. Being clever about the implementation, you can "do row-lstm for each pixel in the image" while cacheing a lot of information and only doing the expensive operations a few times

Comment: So one could contain the row-lstm's of each pixel in one lstm cell?

Comment: just to answer for anyone else: essentially each row is an lstm cell